# Custom Validation Using Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

We have an Application that uses a NoSQL DB as its data source for whatever reason.

We need to persist say E.g an Employee Object that has a Department id and an Address with a zip code. If I persist it in an RDBMS with an invalid department id and zipcode. the DB will throw a constraint exception.

But if I use a NOSQL DB I cannot do this Validation. Is there is any way I can use Hibernate validator and check in DB whether a zip code or department id exist in the DB. Before saving it in DB

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AccessingTheHibernateSessionWithinAConstraintValidator) on the JBoss developer forums that describes how to access the Hibernate Session in a custom validator.  It's a bit dated, so you may have to make some tweaks.